# how to remove count from a plotly express bar chart hover data?

Tags: python, plotly

Given the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'col2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig = px.bar(df, y='col1', color='col1')
fig.show()
```

that generates the following bar plot:

[image]

how do I remove count from hover_data?

plotly==5.1.0

Comment: try this:`import plotly.graph_objects as go;fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=df['col2'], y=df['col1'], orientation='h', hoverinfo='skip')])`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it from `hovertemplate`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'col2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig = px.bar(df, y='col1', color='col1').update_traces(hovertemplate='col1=%{y}<br><extra></extra>')
fig.show()
```